# Iptables route specific port outside VPN (Tomato router firmware)

Tags: router, vpn, iptables, openvpn, tomato

Im trying to configure my router to what I feel is the perfect setup for me. I have managed to connect the router to my VPN-provider (PIA), and routed such that only one computer connects through VPN via iptables (see answere #4 https://serverfault.com/questions/382498/howto-only-tunnel-specific-hosts-route-through-openvpn-client-on-tomato). Im have not any previous experience with IPtables,

I do some gaming, and then the extra latency by using a VPN is undesired. How can I route the specific gaming ports to go directly through my WAN without VPN.

I did find this guide (First answere http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/route-only-specific-ports-through-vpn-openvpn.37240/), but I dont manage to apply that to my situation.

My current IPTable script is this, which only route the correct computer through vpn.

```
sleep 30
ip route flush table 200
ip route flush cache
ip rule add from 192.168.1.143 lookup 200
VPN_GW=`ifconfig tun11 | awk '/inet addr/ {split ($2,A,":"); print A[2]}'`
ip route add table 200 default via $VPN_GW dev tun11
```

So how do I expand this such that the vpn computer (.143) uses direct connection for trafic on port 27000:27050 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add an iptables rule to *mark* specific packets:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 27000:27050 -j MARK --set-mark 0x200
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 27000:27050 -j MARK --set-mark 0x200
```

(You didn't specify whether you want TCP ports or UDP ports, so here are both.)

Then add a policy routing rule that matches the mark:

```
ip rule add fwmark 0x200 lookup main
```

There are other possible combinations – for example, mark all packets meant for VPN (making the existing `from` rule unnecessary).

Comment: Thanks! Works great. This inspires me to try to learn more about iptables because of its great capabilites. Now my dream setup have become true.